How Do I Add a Multiple Testing Correction to Multiple Planned Contrasts in R?
I am new-ish to R and am trying to use it to conduct a large amount of planned contrasts for a bunch of experiments and am struggling to apply multiple testing corrections to the test. To briefly summarize, I have a data frame containing information for the "Site" of my experiment, the "Time" that experiment was done, the "Treatment" applied, and the "Response" to the treatment. With support from the literature, I am primarily interested in two comparisons (see code) between treatment types and want to conduct a planned contrast to investigate those two responses. The problem is, when I block by time, I would like to apply a multiple testing correction (bonferroni) for each test, but I have been stuck for a few days trying to figure it out how to do it.
While I tried to keep this example simple, I also have many response measurements and sites, so it is important that my function can accommodate them all.
Reproducible Example:
library(stats)

Site <- c(rep("a", 20), rep("b", 20))
Time <- rep(c("w", "x", "y", "z"), times = 10)
Treatment <- c(rep("l", 8), rep("m", 8), rep("n", 8),
               rep("o", 8), rep("p", 8))
Response <- runif(40, min = 0, max = 20)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Site, Time, Treatment, Response))

#Setting levels for the treatments:
df$Treatment <- factor(x = df$Treatment, levels = c("l", "m", "n", "o", "p"))

# Define a function to perform a planned contrast for a given site
perform_planned_contrast <- function(data, var) {
  site <- unique(data$Site)[1]  # Get the site name
  cat("\nSite:", site, "| Variable:", var, "\n")     # Print the site name

  # Building hypothesis vectors
  c1 <- c(0, 0, 1, -1, 0) # Contrasting treatments n & o
  c2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, -1) # Contrasting treatments o & p
  
  # Combining these hypotheses into a matrix
  mat <- cbind(c1, c2)
  
  # Applying the hypothesis to the treatment variable
  contrasts(data$Treatment) <- mat
  
  # Build ANOVA model
  anova_result <- aov(as.formula(paste(var, "~ Treatment + Time")), data = data)
  print(summary(anova_result))
  
  # Planned Contrast
  PC <- summary(anova_result, split=list(Treatment=list("3 vs 4"=1,
                                                        "4 vs 5"= 2)))
  
  print(PC)
}

# Apply the function to each unique site
result <- lapply(split(df, df$Site), perform_planned_contrast,
                 var = "Response")


I have tried creating a new column to my "PC" object where I am applying the correction to my p values but this does not work for two reasons. The output of the PC$p.adjust is 0, and I do not think it is accounting for each unique Site I am running through my lapply function.
I added this to my perform_planned_contrast function just before print(PC)
 PC$p.adjust <- p.adjust(PC$p.value, method = "bonferroni")

I think the actual solution might have to modify the lapply output, but I am truly lost at how I would go about doing that.
Thanks for your help!

I changed your function slightly (code below) to return a "tidy" version of the result, via broom::tidy(), which is easier to work with programmatically. I've done this with tidyverse, but it could be done easily in base R as well with lapply(), do.call(rbind, ...),  na.omit(), etc..
library(dplyr)
result <- (split(dd, dd$Site)
    |> purrr::map_dfr(
          ~perform_planned_contrast(., var = "Response"), .id = "Site")
    |> tidyr::drop_na()  ## drop residual terms (no p-value anyway)
    |> mutate(p.adj = p.adjust(p.value, "bonferroni"))
)


Here I took out the print statements and returned a tidied value.
perform_planned_contrast <- function(data, var) {
  site <- unique(data$Site)[1]  # Get the site name
  ## cat("\nSite:", site, "| Variable:", var, "\n")     # Print the site name

  # Building hypothesis vectors
  c1 <- c(0, 0, 1, -1, 0) # Contrasting treatments n & o
  c2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, -1) # Contrasting treatments o & p
  
  # Combining these hypotheses into a matrix
  mat <- cbind(c1, c2)
  
  # Applying the hypothesis to the treatment variable
  contrasts(data$Treatment) <- mat
  
  # Build ANOVA model
  anova_result <- aov(as.formula(paste(var, "~ Treatment + Time")), data = data)
  ## print(summary(anova_result))
  
  # Planned Contrast
  PC <- summary(anova_result, split=list(Treatment=list("3 vs 4"=1,
                                                        "4 vs 5"= 2)))
  broom::tidy(PC[[1]])
}

